# Dual boot encryption and shared data drives

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 with shared data drives and have everything encrypted?  I've read the post here on how to install Ubuntu in a dual boot setup with encryption, but it doesn't mention encrypted shared data drives.
I have things like media files I would like to be able to access from both operating systems.

Comment: You may be able to do that with a third party multiplatform tool such as Veracrypt.

Comment: @MichaelBay If I'm understanding this correctly, VeraCrypt can be installed and run on *nix to access VeraCrypt encrypted drives, but it will not encrypt a *nix partition.  I would have to use other software for that.  This is okay with me though as I don't want to get into the Ubuntu install while in Windows.  I just want to access some shared media storage drives.

Comment: Veracrypt can be used create encrypted **files** (containers) or encrypted **volumes**: *Formats and encrypts a non-system partition, entire external or secondary drive,  entire USB stick, etc.* Either way it does what you want but using just a file is much easier and enough for your goal. Do not over-complicate what doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **not** possible or at least not as easy as you would be wanting.  Ubuntu uses a specific set of libraries to mange encryption/decryption when logging in/out of the user account.  This method would not be available in the Windows OS.

To access an encrypted drive in Windows you would need some tools that replicate how Ubuntu encrypts the data as well as having the key available to do the decryption.  Last I saw Windows would not even see a Linux filesystem type let alone be able to read the key from it.

Comment: I don't expect or want to see the Linux installation from Windows.  I want them both to be able to access encrypted storage drives.

Comment: @tubtwo Same thing, some limitations.